# Javascript keyup / onkeyup wrong element

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup, onkeyup

Is anyone having the same issue?
When typing quickly into a textbox and skip to a next textbox (by pushing the 'tab' key) the keyup event is registered from the wrong element.

Behaviour:

1. **Precondition:** We have two textboxes; with javascript registrered to the key-up event
2. **Action:** Type quicky in textbox and switch to next textbox with 'tab' key.
3. **End situation**: All the pressed characters are rendered in the first textbox and the second textbox is selected (but empty); Javascript keyup events registers the last x (depends on type speed) from the last element.(unexpected)

**Expected end situation:**
- All the pressed characters are rendered in the first textbox and the second textbox is selected (but empty); 
Javascript: only the last ('tab' keyup event) is registered from the last element.

*(this problem is in plain javascript but also propagates to jQuery onkeyup events)*

Tested in browsers:
- Chrome (Version 49.0.2623.87 m (64-bit))
- FireFox (45.0.1)
- Edge

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xk09542f/4/

js:

```
document.getElementById('inp1').onkeyup = function(e) {
     console.log(this.id + ' ' + e.which);
}
document.getElementById('inp2').onkeyup = function(e) {
  console.log(this.id + ' ' + e.which);
}
```

html:

```
<input id="inp1" type="text">
<input id="inp2" type="text">
```

output: see console;

Comment: you know that `keyup` is fire when you release the key ? so if you release the key after you pressed tab then it's the expected behaviour

Comment: Take this fiddle this would be fairly esier for you to debug ;) 
https://jsfiddle.net/xk09542f/5/

Comment: It even gets stranger when also printing the key down events too; this also registers the events for the wrong element. see fiddle: jsfiddle.net/xk09542f/6
See image: [Image](http://s7.postimg.org/c7naut3t7/jq_keyup.png).

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you see in the console is the expected result, because :
When you press tab key its handle 2 events first one is keyDown (which will move you to the second textField) now you are in second textField and you still under keyDown event , so when you release the tab key its handle your keyUp event  and this last event happened on the second textField.